# How to put all rows in a column to a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have written a stored procedure as

```
Declare @Split table
(
 Jurisdiction nvarchar(max)
)

Insert into @Split select Jurisdiction from tbLicence where AgentId =@AgentId;

Select * from @Split;

Declare @products varchar(MAX);

Select @products = Jurisdiction from @Split;

Select @products;
```

I want to put all the values of column @Split in @products variable.
Please note that above code is putting only last row's column value in @products.
Please help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Initialize the variable with `empty string`. Then append all the rows using any delimiter. Use this.

```
DECLARE @products VARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @products += Isnull(Jurisdiction, '') + ','
FROM   @Split;

SELECT left(@products,len(@products)-1);
```

or Use `For XML path()`

```
set @products=(select ','+Jurisdiction from @Split for xml path(''))

select right(@products,len(@products)-1)
```

Comment: Plus one. Good solution without a loop :)

Answer (score 0):

This might helps you

```
Declare @Split table( Jurisdiction nvarchar(max))
Declare @products varchar(MAX)=''
declare @count int=(select count(*) from @split)
declare @a int=1

Insert into @Split values ('a'),('b')


while(@a<@count)
begin
    Select @products += Jurisdiction from @Split 
    set @a=@a+1

end

select @products
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nida... you can do that using xml path as well... , but it will  concatenate all values  with comma seperator. I have done thru xml path... Might be it will help you...

**Sample Values in dbo.columnnames**

```
Value One
Value Two
Value Three
Value Four
Value Five
```

**QUERY**

```
declare @lv_table table( column_values varchar(100))
declare @product_v varchar(max)
insert into @lv_table
select * from dbo.columnnames
set  @product_v =(

select 
    Stuff(
        (
    SELECT  ',' + column_values 
    FROM  @lv_table
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') )

    select @product_v
```

**Output**

```
Value One,Value Two,Value Three,Value Four,Value Five
```